# Get generate autoincrement id after an insert query performed- HANA

Tags: hana

I want to get the autoincrement id of an insert using HANA database.
We have tried searching on internet also tried using JDBC keyholder option.
support for autoincrement came recently to HANA and I am not getting example
for same.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I assume with "autoincrement" you mean the IDENTITY column option that came with HANA SPS 8?

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE <table_name> (<column_name> <num_data_type
  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY);
```

This blog post explains how that works:
 https://blogs.sap.com/2014/06/04/quick-note-on-identity-column-in-sap-hana/

--- *Quote:* ---

The magic behind this is of course created by **sequences**:

```
select column_name, column_id from table_columns where table_name = 'SOME_NAMES'

+-------------+-----------+
| COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_ID |
+-------------+-----------+
| ID          |    145210 |
| NAME        |    145211 |
+-------------+-----------+

select * from sequences where sequence_name like ‘%145210%’

+-------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
| SCHEMA_NAME |  SEQUENCE_NAME            | SEQUENCE_OID | START_NUMBER | MIN_VALUE | MAX_VALUE        | INCREMENT_BY | IS_CYCLED | RESET_BY_QUERY                            | CACHE_SIZE |
+-------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
| SYSTEM      | _SYS_SEQUENCE_145210_#0_# |    145215    |     1        |    1      |       4611686018 |              |           |                                           |            |
+-------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Aaaaand, that’s it.

--- *End Quote* ---

From here you can use **CURRVAL** to get the last generated value.

```
SELECT SYSTEM."_SYS_SEQUENCE_145210_#0_#".CURRVAL FROM DUMMY
```

Comment: thanks..does there way to get data in insert query response

Comment: @Vish: No, you need to send the SELECT as second query afterwards, ideally in a transaction. Alternatively, you could write a stored procedure that does the insert and returns the new autoincrement id.